# Loading the right bean in the test profile in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans, spring-bean

My application.yaml has the following entries:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: test
    include: h2, test
key:
 enabled: on
```

I have the following three bean definitions and would like to load the TestConfig bean in my tests. But it takes NoConfig Bean in the tests:

```
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "key.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
    @Profile("test")
    public class TestConfig {}

    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Config.class)
    public class NoConfig {}

   @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "key.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
   @Profile("!test")
   public class Config{}
```

I also check the active profile in the test, and it is indeed test profile.

```
@Value("${spring.profiles.active:Unknown}")
private String activeProfile;
```

Comment: **key.enabled** is not a boolean; try with `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "key.enabled", havingValue ="on", matchIfMissing = true)`

Comment: I can see it loads both `TestConfig` and `NoConfig`. Tested it in my local. Can you push a sample code to GitHub, so that we can tell what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Bean `NoConfig` you have is always created when there is no bean `Config`. You can try to use `@TestConfiguration` to define beans needed for a particular test, or you can write a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to exclude unnecessary bean from initialisation

Or try to add `havingValue` attribute in `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation and change `key.enabled` attribute in yaml file to set the value of it to `true`

Comment: I already did it, see: @Profile("test")
    public class TestConfig

Comment: No I mean the @TestConfiguration annotation. See : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/TestConfiguration.html

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt change anything to use TestConfiguration instead of Configuration annotation on this class.

Comment: @jd466 try to add `havingValue` attribute in `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation and change `key.enabled` attribute in yaml file to set the value of it to `true`